# In Need of Basic Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

QUESTION: Why am I being thrown the following line:

```
/Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jrails-0.6.0/lib/jrails.rb:231:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptProxy (NameError)
```

ENV:

- OS X 10.7
- Rails 3.1.0.rc5

I have seen (spent many more hours trying to debug it myself):

- [Rails3 server and bundler error: uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282969/rails3-server-and-bundler-error-uninitialized-constant-bundler-nameerror)

**- more info available upon request**

## ANY IDEAS? I'm baffled.

Here is the full output from console...

```
dcarpenter$ rails s
    /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jrails-0.6.0/lib/jrails.rb:231:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptProxy (NameError)
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jrails-0.6.0/lib/jrails.rb:2:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jrails-0.6.0/lib/jrails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.17/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/Dropbox/workspace/BlueFusion/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /Users/dcarpenter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
dcarpenter$
```

Answer (score 1):

How come you're using jRails? Try removing it from your life as it's no longer actively developed and I wonder if it might be the source of your problem...

jQuery is the new default thesedays anyway so your don't need jrails...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Do you know why it is no longer actively devloped?

Comment: because jquery is the new default in rails3 so it became defunkt

Comment: Almost ready to vote ya up. Thanks for your help. By the new default, does that mean that I don't need to install any gems?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2246/discussion-between-drew-and-stephenmurdoch)

Comment: Still looking for a way to keep the rest of the code encapsulated not have to remove jrails and replace the corresponding code.